# Conditionally get ACF field in Wordpress nav walker based on parent menu item?

Tags: custom-field, menus, walker

I am building out a mega menu for a site and I have some ACF fields set up that I want to display in each of the sub-menus in the navigation. I want to specify which field to used based on which parent menu item's sub-menu is currently active. I have started building out a custom nav walker but I'm not really sure how I can go about conditionally getting those custom fields based on the parent menu item.

I have my walker set up like this to prepare the sub-menu container elements:

```
class Sub_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"sub-menu-container\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
    
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $item, $args = array()) {
        // Conditionaly get field based on parent element
        $sub_menu_fields = get_field('lorem', 'option');
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        foreach ($sub_menu_fields as $field) :
            $output.= "<div>Custom sub-menu content goes here</div>";
        endforeach;
        $output .= "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to pass a dynamic ACF field name into my `get_field()` call based on the parent menu item's name. I think I am going to need to use [start_el()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/) for this, so I added this:

```
function start_el( &$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_item = $object->post_name;
}
```

This gets me the slug of each of the menu items but I'm not sure how to combine this to conditionally select which field to use in the `end_lvl()` function. Any ideas?